# Excel Formula to remove special characters from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I want to remove special characters from a cell in Excel. I have tried that using a module and that works fine but I want to do it through a formula. The formula should work for all the special characters including spaces:

> ~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=<>,?/\|

The macro I have tried is like this:

```
Function RemoveSpclChrs(Str As String) As String
    Dim xChars As String
    Dim I As Long
    xChars = "/~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=<>,?\|"
    For I = 1 To Len(xChars)
        Str = Replace$(Str, Mid$(xChars, I, 1), "")
    Next
    Remove = Str
End Function
```

I know I could use SUBSTITUTE function but that would be real burden. So I was looking for a more simpler formula. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks for the help.